# MySQL: Corrupt ARCHIVE table. Help, Please?

Tags: linux, mysql, corruption

I'm a programmer and a total newbie as a sysadmin...

Today I started receiving error emails from our production site:

```
Incorrect key file for table 'xxx'; try to repair it
```

I found the server with 2 out of 4 cores pegged at 100% CPU by MySQL. Took down the site, the crons, everything, and about 10 minutes later CPU went to 0.

Trying to backup the DB (mysqldump) resulted in CPU at 100% again, for several minutes, without any real output to log file.

I tried REPAIR TABLE, got this:

```
+----------------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| Table                      | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+----------------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| db.table                   | repair | error    | Corrupt  |
+----------------------------+--------+----------+----------+
```

So that didn't work...

I thought of creating a new table (InnoDB) and "INSERT SELECT" from this one to try and recover some records, but SELECTING from the table (SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1) also sends the CPU to 100% for a couple minutes, and again gives me the "Incorrect key file" error...

I got this error for 3 of the 4 tables in this DB, all 3 of them use the ARCHIVE engine and have several million records. (Largest is 46M records)

This started about an hour ago, all of a sudden.

Any ideas what I should do next? I would ideally like to lose as few records as possible, but at the same time I need to get the site back up ASAP.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
Daniel

Comment: How recent is the most recent backup, to get an idea of how many records you'd lose?

Comment: Sorry I missed this comment. I'd hope last night. My client's supposed to have arranged backups with the hosting company, but I don't know for a fact. I'm hoping to not have to count on Backups, ideally, and there may be none.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL had a long-standing bug with Archive tables starting to corrupt after they got bigger than 2 GB. How big is your table?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. How do I check that? (NOTE: Trying to query information_schema.tables sends the CPU to 100% again) :-(

Comment: In an old dev copy that I have (few weeks / months ago), largest table is 365 Mb, it can't have grown to 2Gb in the time since that dump...

Comment: Never say never, check at the file system level. And is there disk space left in your DB partition?

Comment: How can I check at the FS level? (Sorry, i'm a noob at this)
There's 100Gb free according to DF

Comment: See with ls command in your MySQL data directory, /var/lib/mysql or so.

Comment: Damn, don't have permissions to that folder :-(
(not a root at this server)
Any other options?

Comment: What does SHOW TABLE STATUS tell you?

Comment: Ok, managed to get in there.... None of the files are even close to 1Gb. Closest is 800 Mb

Comment: SHOW TABLE STATUS kills CPU for several minutes and doesn't show anything. I've killed it after 5 minutes.

Comment: Ok, so not about that bug this time. Then I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

We had a corrupt ARCHIVE format table. Looked like it crashed in the middle of OPTIMIZE or REPAIR, with the size of the files.

Running REPAIR TABLE $tablename EXTENDED; twice fixed it, as per this old bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/maria/+bug/881383

Worth a try before running to your backups.